# How to install Django REST ApI framework on Windows? I've Django1.7 Development version

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to install Django rest framework on Windows.I couldn't install it with pip or git commands.
Also I want to know whether it works with Django 1.7 Development version or I need to install official version of Django

Comment: `pip` is not a linux command, it's a command line tool. http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: Here is a guide to install `pip` on Windows http://arunrocks.com/guide-to-install-python-or-pip-on-windows/

Comment: git is not a Linux tool either. If you're going to be using Django on Windows, though, you'd really better learn to use both git and pip.

Comment: This is the url for django rest framework = https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework/                       The pip & git are command line utilities on linux, we can install them on windows as well from the following url = http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: The django rest framework also works with development version not only with official version.You can read the documents related to these version from django's official site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the url for [Django Rest framework][1] = pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework.
The pip & git are command line utilities, we can install them on windows.
Refer this URL:
pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

The django rest framework also works with development version not only with official version.More details can be found django's official site below:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework/

Comment: This is incorrect and spreading falsities. As mentioned in the comments above `git` and `pip` are **NOT** linux commands/tools. They are general *cross-platform* command line utilities. Git is used for version control of code-bases, while *PIP* is the package manager for *Python*.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to run the following in your shell:

```
pip install djangorestframework
```